# How to unit test modules that work together as subprocesses via pipes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, subprocess, integration-testing

I'm writing a program that acts as a script manager. It consists of 3 parts:

1. A client - Receives a script name to run from the server.
2. Manager - Manages running scripts. Receives them from the client using a json transferred in a Pipe.
3. The scrips - `.py` scripts that are found under the `addons` directory in the project.

The important thing to notice is that all 3 components run simultaneously as processes (because I could have an **alarm** script running while accepting and executing a **play music** script.

Because it consists of 3 separate parts that interact with each other I don't know how to write proper unit tests for it.

So my questions are:

1. How can I write good unit tests for this?
2. Is this a design problem? if so, what am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix it?

Here is most of the code for the above components:

**The Client**

```
class MessageReceiver:

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Connect to the AMQP broker and starts listening for messages.
        Creates the a Popen object to pass command info to the addon_manager script (which
        is in charge of managing scripts)
        '''
        addon_manager_path = configuration.addon_manager_path()
        addon_manager_path = os.path.join(addon_manager_path,'addon_manager.py')
        execute = "python " + addon_manager_path
        self.addon_manager = subprocess.Popen(execute, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)


        self.component_name= configuration.get_attribute("name")

        if len(sys.argv)>1:
            host_ip = sys.argv[1]
        else:
            host_ip = 'localhost'

        #Start a connection to the AMQP server
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=host_ip))

        #Create a channel to the server
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        self.channel.queue_declare(queue="example")

        #callback method to be called when data is received
        #It sends the data that is received by the client to the addon_manager
        def data_received(ch, method, properties, body):
            ##TODO: Might want to add some checks. Is body a JSON? etc.
            print("GOT IT")
            self.addon_manager.communicate(body)


        self.channel.basic_consume(data_received,queue='example',no_ack=True)

        self.channel.start_consuming()
```

**The Manager**

```
class AddonManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.command_analyzer = analyzer.Analyzer(configuration.get_attribute("commands"))
        self.active_addons = {}


    def activate_addon(self,command,json_data):
        child_popen = self.command_analyzer.execute_command(command,json_data)
        self.active_addons[analyzer.intent(json_data)] = child_popen


    def communicate_with_addon(self,command,json_data,json_string):
        child_popen = self.active_addons[analyzer.intent(json_data)]

        #Child process hasn't finished running
        if child_popen.returncode is None:
            #Send data to child to process if he wants to
            child_popen.stdin.write(json_string)

        else:
            #Process finished running. Can't send it anything. delete it. (deleting the Popen instance also kills zombie process)
            del self.active_addons[analyzer.intent(json_data)]
            self.activate_addon(command,json_data)


    def get_input(self):
        """
        Reads command from stdin, returns its JSON form
        """
        json_string = sys.stdin.read()
        json_data =json.loads(json_string)
        print(json_data)
        return json_data


    def accept_commands(self):
        while True:
            json_data = self.get_input()
            command = self.command_analyzer.is_command(json_data) # Check wether the command exists. Return it if it does
            #The command exists
            if command is not None:
                #The addon is not currently active
                if analyzer.intent(json_data) not in self.active_addons:
                    self.activate_addon(command,json_data)

                #The addon is active and so we need to send the data to the subprocess
                else:
                    self.communicate_with_addon(command,json_data,json_string)


manager = AddonManager()
manager.accept_commands()
```

Comment: What is it to be, integration testing or unit testing? The two types are quite far apart. A unit test doesn't require any of the other parts; anything outside of the Code Under Test is mocked, scripted to produce specific responses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - You're right. My bad. I'm interested in unit tests. I think the integration tests are closer to acceptance tests in this case (in the sense that I'll just need to run it and see if it works).

Comment: me thinks it could be useful to do a bit of both. (without knowing python well) to write proper unit tests you will need to mock stdin and stdout. *or* (as I often prefer) put the interesting code to test in methods without deps on the outside world.